# What is  $i^{i^{\,{}^{.\,^{.\,^{.\,^i}}}}}$ equal to?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, exponentiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compute the infinite tower of the complex number $i$, that is$ ^{\infty}i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17578/how-to-compute-the-infinite-tower-of-the-complex-number-i-that-is-inftyi)

Define $a_0 = i$, and $a_n = i^{a_{n-1}}$.

What is

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{a_n} = i^{i^{\,{}^{.\,^{.\,^{.\,^i}}}}} = ~~~? $$

Comment: This is equivalent to the solution of $i^x = x$.

Comment: It's possible that it doesn't even converge, so that trick may not work, Strin.

Comment: Well, what branch shall you choose?

Comment: This blog article on Walking Randomly is related but does not answer your specific question: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=294

Comment: Smells like $W$.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17578/how-to-compute-the-infinite-tower-of-the-complex-number-i-that-is-inftyi) seems on the same subject.